# cropping an image by using an custom view

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to crop an image by using a view.
I added the custom view to the UIImagePickerController and took some photos but the results weren't the part that the view takes up and they seem quite zoomed in...

at the bottom of the code, rect.frame is the custom view's frame.

```
  func cropIt( rect: CGRect) -> UIImage {

    
          let image = UIImage(cgImage: image.cgImage!.cropping(to: rect)!, scale: 1, orientation: image.imageOrientation)
           return image
          
       }
    
    assignedImage.image = cropIt(rect: rect.frame)
  

}
```

Comment: To clarify, you want the resulting image to be the same size as your view but cropped at the center?

Comment: @RobertCrabtree yes! I want the resulting image to be the same size as my customView (not the self.view) and not copped at the center.

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question:

```
public func crop(image: UIImage, toRect rect: CGRect) -> UIImage {
  let orientation = image.imageOrientation
  let scale = image.scale
  var targetRect = CGRect()

  switch orientation {
  case .down:
    targetRect.origin.x = (image.size.width - rect.maxX) * scale
    targetRect.origin.y = (image.size.height - rect.maxY) * scale
    targetRect.size.width = rect.width * scale
    targetRect.size.height = rect.height * scale
  case .right:
    targetRect.origin.x = rect.minY * scale
    targetRect.origin.y = (image.size.width - rect.maxX) * scale
    targetRect.size.width = rect.height * scale
    targetRect.size.height = rect.width * scale
  case .left:
    targetRect.origin.x = image.size.height - rect.maxY * scale
    targetRect.origin.y = rect.minX * scale
    targetRect.size.width = rect.height * scale
    targetRect.size.height = rect.width * scale
  default:
    targetRect = CGRect(x: rect.origin.x * scale,
                        y: rect.origin.y * scale,
                        width: rect.width * scale,
                        height: rect.height * scale)
  }

  if let croppedCGImage = image.cgImage?.cropping(to: targetRect) {
    return UIImage(cgImage: croppedCGImage, scale: scale, orientation: orientation)
  }

  return image
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. I called the function like this         [ResultVC.image = crop(image: image, toRect: rect.frame)]
 but the result picture is zoomed up and the taken part is very close from the CGPoint.. (the custom view is much bigger from CGPoint..) it seems like I'm having a problem with converting cgpoint and pixel going back and forth..

Comment: To check whether the above function work as expected or not I think you should use some tests you created before giving the function the real values you get from your view (photo editor maybe?). So you know which part should be fixed.

Comment: with the limited knowledge that I have, it's hard to figure out.. I have been trying to figure out where I'm doing wrong.. could you please take a look at my code? I'm going to update the question with the code if you're available to do so.

Comment: FYI: i’m using the func above to make the cropping feature for this lib: https://github.com/congnd/FMPhotoPicker . You may want to take a look at this. I don’t know how do you pass the rect to the func so it’s hard for me to find out the issue. But for the function itself, i think it has no problem.